# Singular or multiple structs?

Tags: c++, struct

I want to use structs to make my code more organized but which one is more suited and also the amount of things I need put into structs is about 30+, and if the former is better what is the limit? Or just a better idea in general if there is one.

```
struct blah1
{
   int x;
   int y;
} w, e, f;
```

or should I use this?

```
struct blah2
{
   int x;
   int y;
} w;

struct blah3
{
   int x;
   int y;
} e;

struct blah1
{
   int x;
   int y;
} r;
```

Comment: Multiple structures is okay if they are for different things. If `w`, `e` and `r` are the same "kind" of thing, then declaring multiple structures makes no sense. And if you have structures that builds on each other then you of course can use inheritance instead of declaring multiple structures that looks almost the same.

Comment: You tag c++, so why not using classes?

Comment: If they're exactly the same, including member names, then just use one.  Don't name the members generically in a misguided attempt to re-use code, though.

Comment: @jpo38 Maybe the OP just want a simple POD type with all public members?

Comment: @jpo38 I think mainly because the OP want public access by default.

Comment: @Lingxi Yes wanted public by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C++ struct declaration style reminds me of the C-style syntax, which is arcane for modern C++. Use the following syntax for C++ compilers:

```
struct myType
{
   int x;
   int y;
};

myType a{0, 1};
myType b{2, 3};
```

- C++ does not require a `typedef` to remove the struct, and leaving your variables uninitialized with only the declaration is bad style. Treat the `struct` definition as if it were a type declaration, and then use the regular `type varname(constructor_arg);` syntax.
- Modern C++ also accepts the new brace-initialized syntax. For a simple structure like this `myType`, it is useful to not have to write a constructor and simply infer from the simple definition that `a.x = 0; a.y = 1;`

If your objects have a similar type and structure, just use the same type. Use the type system to your advantage to not repeat yourself when programming and reduce repetition of extraneous code.